# How do cut some part from y-axis in R?

Tags: r, plot, cut, yaxis

I have a data as a matrix in the following form:

```r
mj = matrix(c(1:63),9)
m  = seq(1,21,3)

plot(m, mj[1,],type="l")
for(i in 2:7){
  lines(m,mj[i,],type="l")
}
```

[image: img]

I do not need to visualize some part of the graph. For example, how can I take only the curve from `ylim=c(0,20)` and `ylim=c(30,40)` removing rest of the plot?

Comment: Do you want the axes on the graph to still run from 0 to 50, or to break as well?

Comment: Yes i want the graph to still run from 0 to 50 but middle part need to be removed.

Comment: Another thing is that by looking at yaxis one should know that some part is actually removed. That is I edit to make the graph more interpretable.

Comment: Have a search here on Stackoverflow for `[r] axis.break` - that function should have been used to do this sort of thing a few times.

Answer (score -1):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggbreak)

mj=matrix(c(1:63),9)
m=seq(1,21,3)

x = m

y1 = mj[1,]
y2 = mj[2,]
y3 = mj[3,]
y4 = mj[4,]
y5 = mj[5,]
y6 = mj[6,]
y7 = mj[7,]
y8 = mj[8,]
y9 = mj[9,]

data = data.frame(x, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7, y8, y9)

p1 = ggplot(data, aes(x)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = y1, colour = "y1")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = y2, colour = "y2")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = y3, colour = "y3")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = y4, colour = "y4")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = y5, colour = "y5")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = y6, colour = "y6")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = y7, colour = "y7")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = y8, colour = "y8")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = y9, colour = "y9"))

p1 + scale_y_break(c(20, 30))
```

[plot with break](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Smnbl.png)

Comment: I want to remove the part ylim=c(20,40). You actually took it.

Comment: Changed code to help answer correctly